# Are there Business Cards for this site?

Tags: discussion, business-cards

I have just been reading [the stackoverflow blog post about business cards](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/).  Are we getting them for our site?  I would love something like this to hand out to photographer friends! - To advertise the site, I mean.

Comment: Are there any big upcoming conferences, by the way, or is this just for a general promotion effort?

Comment: Just a general comment.  I was thinking about something I can give to friends, because I think lots of people would love the site, but just don't get around to trying it just because I tell them about it.  Something physical to give them would help, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Worth point out that there now are now [business cards for moderators](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1504/21); so yes, there are for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there are no business card designs done for the Photo site.

[Jin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4/jin), our designer, does intend to get around to these designs, but they are not currently on his plate.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Grace Note said...

If you don't want to wait for our designer to get around to making business cards, you are more than welcome to create your own. The general Stack Exchange logos are available [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos). You're more than welcome to use those in designing your own flyers or business cards (either the Stack Exchange network, or turning it into a Photo SE specific design). If you do that and come up with a great design, share it here so other people can use it, too. :)