# Photo Stack Exchange swag

Tags: discussion, swag

We're working on custom swag for the photo.SE community. Based on [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/conversation/photo-se-promotion-brainstorm-1) session and [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/conversation/photo-se-promotion-brainstorm-1-b) we are thinking of making Photo Stack Exchange branded camera straps and 18% gray lens cloths. What do you guys think? Would these be cool and useful for you? Do you have any *even more awesome* ideas for merch? Leave your feedback below!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to make new tags...if someone could add the tag "swag" to this, I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: Thank you to you and Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 8):

I'd *use* a microfiber cloth, because that's practical. So sure. It' s not very exciting. I probably wouldn't use a camera strap; I already have a nice one, and it isn't covered in branding.

Comment: Even better if said cloth was 18% grey, too :)

Comment: @Rowland: okay for exposure, but would you trust a cloth for color accuracy?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Your wish came true!

Answer (score 4):

High quality stickers? I might stick one on my laptop and possibly on some random gear.

Comment: Photo.SE stickers are likely to appear at some point in the future...if you just can't wait, we do have some general Stack Exchange stickers in the store! http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a regular camera strap, as I have a perfectly good strap that came with my camera, but if it had something unique about it... I might be interested in a extra-comfortable padded strap or especially a sling-style ([1](http://www.blackrapid.com/product/camera-strap/rs-7/)),([2](http://www.luma-labs.com/loop)) strap.

Comment: Thanks for the links to examples!

Answer (score 2):

What about lens covers or frame?

Comment: I would definitely use a snap-on lens cap in 49mm thread.

Comment: This is a neat idea, but I'm worried about the number of sizes that lenses come in. If people can list the sizes they want/need, I'll see if there's enough people with the same sizes to warrant getting a couple different options.

Answer (score 1):

You know we're all just in it for the badges, right? So how about some little pin badges in bronze, silver and gold? Perhaps even a variety pack with a bunch of bronzes, a few silvers and a gold. :)

Comment: Physical badges with pure grade metals, please. ;P

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there's the idea of [business cards](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/21), perhaps featuring their photos on the reverse, with details on t' front - might be more useful for the semi-pros, rather than the pros on here, but I'll through that idea into this mix :)

Answer (score 0):

I think camera straps will be nice, specially if they're **nicely padded**. I also like the idea of HQ [waterproof/weatherproof](http://www.discountbannerprinting.co.uk/stickers/waterproof-weatherproof-stickers.html) stickers. Also an online badge showing reputation, rank etc can be handy for people having their own website.

Comment: For the badge to show online; have you seen: http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2476/shutterbug?tab=flair ?

Comment: Ahhh! I had a feeling its already there... thanks ;)