# Photography SE moderator cards

Tags: discussion, business-cards

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator, would you be interested in having your own Photography Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to photographers friends or local photo meetups.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: Photography SE moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely. People love my StackExchange t-shirt. It would be great to have some business cards to spread the word about StackExchange (and more specifically PhotoSE) as well. I think our site has it a little harder than more technical sites here on SE, and having some physical medium to share the word with other photographers out in the real world would be a real bonus.

Also, it might be useful to offer them to the top non-moderator high-rep users as well? Particularly actual professionals, who might have a better opportunity to share their cards and spread the word.

---

Just wanted to say **Thanks!** Finally got my cards, they are great!

[image]

Comment: I will be making generic photo.se site cards for everyone soon. I'm  currently trying to get all the SE sites' mod cards done first.

Comment: StachExchange, you say? Is that where you go and trade in your handlebar for a pencil or walrus? :)

Comment: @mattdm: LOL! Point taken, typo fixed. :P

Comment: BTW, @Jin, Mattdm most definitely deserves to have some business cards. Even though he is not a mod, he works just as hard, if not harder half the time, to keep our site pristine.

Comment: +1 for mattdm deserving one; I actually thought he *was* a moderator!

Comment: Ditto for @rfusca for all the blog admin stuff that he performs (if he wants them, of course)

Comment: If there are non-mod cards available in the future, I'd be in to getting them and sharing them around southern Ontario for sure. Might be a good way to explain why I'm always lugging two SLRs around too... :)

Answer (score 2):

Can this be made available for top users (the same system as the photography swag) instead of moderators only? If this is about spreading the name, I think it should be made a little broad than this. For example: people having at least X reputation will be eligible to get one if they wish and if they apply.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the cards are now available -- all current moderators were mailed a link to the form to customize the cards. Enjoy!